# Correct initialize out in function

Tags: c#, .net

I'm little lost as a beginner in C# how to use out and return message value in my code.
I need to call function Deserialize on this object and if I reseive right answer from Deserialize return bool value and initialized instance of class, but how?

Text of task: (don't need to help me to solve whole task, only about i said)

**For clarification, you can not read**

Generic method TryReceive, whose generic type will be limited to objects implementing the IMessage interface, which also have a public parametric constructor. This method will have an input parameter receiving serialized message text and an output parameter whose type will be given by the generic type of this method. The method will return a logical value corresponding to whether the acceptance was successful or unsuccessful. In this method, go through the objects registered in the RegisterSerializer method and check if there are any that are of type MessageSerializer, where” T " is the generic type of the TryReceive method. If you find such an object, call the Deserialize method on it (the call parameter will be the serialized text of the message). If the deserialization was successful (no InvalidMessageException exception was thrown), the deserialized message is returned and the TryReceive method is terminated. If deserialization fails, the search for the next suitable object for deserialization will continue.

Code what i call:

```
if (mailbox.TryReceive(txt, out Message message))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("TEXT MESSAGE:");
                    Console.WriteLine(message.Text);
                }
```

My code version:

```
        public bool TryReceive<T>(string serzText, out T param) where T : IMessage, new()
        {
            foreach (MessageSerializerBase Obj in list)
            {
                if (Obj is MessageSerializer<T> temp)
                {
                    param.Deserialize(serzText);
                    param = temp;
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: Can you ask question in less words not like an essay

Comment: @viveknuna main question in header, I added task text if nobody understands.

Comment: You're invoking Deserialize against the uninitialized param output; not sure where list is coming from but pretty sure it should be `param = temp.Deserialize(serzText)`, and should probably handle exceptions to return false, and use meaningful names (temp => serializer or similar).

Comment: The question is fine IMO ;-)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon thanks, i will think about false option. List it's just         List<MessageSerializerBase> list = new(); where i add objects of this class

Comment: *Every* path through the code should assign a value to `param`. This includes where you return false

Comment: @HansKeﬆing i guess if i catch error i can return to param   param = default; Is it right?

Comment: Yes, default/null is a usual value to return on a failed Try*